# How to display Json object in jsp

Tags: java, json, jsp, gson

I'm newbie to jsp. I have a `JSON` coding

```
{"eventDetails":[{"startDate":1387175589253,"eventJSON":"{\"userIp\":\"***.***.***.**\",\"organizationUid\":\"4261-5404a609bd14\",\"userAgent\":\"Restlet-Framework\/2.1m3\",\"currentSessionToken\":\"9f3ee5b076-27dbead458ca\",\"endTime\":1312,\"apiKey\":\"b6bd9-30849cf17727\",\"startTime\":13853,\"sessionToken\":null,\"eventId\":\"4731d1-adb6-10faaa3ee269\",\"userUid\":null,\"userId\":1,\"context\":\"\/v2\/account\/loginas\/anonymous\",\"eventName\":\"user-loginAs\""
```

I need to display eventJSON object as a raw data :

```
{\"userIp\":\"204.236.177.80\",\"organizationUid\":\"4261739e-ccae-11e1-adfb-5404a609bd14\",\"userAgent\":\"Restlet-Framework\/2.1m3\",\"currentSessionToken\":\"9f3ee54a-4f5f-b076-27d8ca\",\"endTime\":1387175589312,\"apiKey\":\"b6b8-4ad5-96d9-3084927\",\"startTime\":1387175589253,\"sessionToken\":null,\"eventId\":\"478e8-4ed1-adb6-10faaa3ee269\",\"userUid\":null,\"userId\":11878,\"context\":\"\/v2\/act\/lonas\/anonymous\",\"eventName\":\"user-loginAs\"}
```

how to display eventJSON using gson and printing with `c:out`.

**JSP Page**

```
<tr id="datalogList-${gC.index}">
<td id = "eventName-${gC.index}">
<c:out value="${datalog.eventName}" />
</td>   
<td id = "startTime-${gC.index}">
<c:out value="${datalog.startTime}" />
</td>  
<td id = "endTime-${gC.index}">
<c:out value="${datalog.endTime}" />
</td>
<td id = "apiKey-${gC.index}"></a>
<c:out value="${datalog.apiKey}" />
</td>
</tr>
```

**Java**

```
  Datalogging[]  logevents = (Datalogging[]) gson.fromJson(eventValueList.toString(),Datalogging[].class);
```

Thanks for reading.