# how to parse array list data and json data in jsp

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring, jsp

I have 2 set of data in my jsp page , one is a `array list` and another is `json data` . Now i want to parse both the data set and create my own drop downs .

Here is the sample `Array List` named `json_obj` data

`["ABC-1","ABC-2","ABC-3","ABC-4","ABC-5","ABC-6"]`

I tried this piece of code but not working

```
<select>
  <option value="all_qns">All</option>
  <c:forEach var="strategy" items="${json_obj}" varStatus="strategyLoop">
    <option><c:out value="${strategyLoop[index]}"/></option>

  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Getting blank options

```
<select>
 <option value="all_qns">All</option>
 <option></option>
 <option></option>
 <option></option>
 <option></option>
 <option></option>
 <option></option>
</select>
```

Also I do have this piece of `json data` named `json_obj_m`

```
{"a":"1050","b":"1079","c":"1073","d":"1074"}
```

And I a=have tried this :

```
<c:forEach items="${json_obj_m}" var="met">
 <option value="${met.key}">${met.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

But not working again getting error , that spring does not support `key` .

Can anybody guide me where I am doing mistake, very new to Java/Spring . Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to construct java object from JSON before applying JSTL tags.

Comment: Ok so can guide me a bit how to do it.

Comment: If you want to try "javascript" approach, you may refer this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756970/how-to-display-json-object-in-jsp

Comment: If you want to try "java" approach, it is better to do it in controller and send it, example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of JSTP `foreach` is incorrect : you get the value in `strategy` and try to use (badly) `strategyLoop` which is the status. You should write simply :

```
<option>${strategy}</option>
```

The status helps to count the iterations and you use `${strategyLoop.index}` or `${strategyLoop.count}`:

- `strategyLoop.index` starts at 0
- `strategyLoop.count` starts at 1

Answer (score 1):

For iterating over list use this code:

```
<select id="someId">
  <option value="all_qns">All</option>
  <c:forEach var="strategy" items="${json_obj}" >
    <option value="${strategy}">${strategy}</option>

  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

And if you are getting JSON through Ajax call, you can use this (By JavaScript):

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) { 
         $('#someId').append("<option value="+key+"option>"+value+"</option>");  
    });
});
```

Comment: `JSON` data works fine , But when I am doing the same for `ArrayList` it is not working . I made it working by `Javascript` as :                                                       `dataMatel = <%=request.getAttribute("json_obj")%>; 
$.each(dataMatel, function(value) { 
    $('#questionID').append("<option value="+dataMatel[value]+">"+dataMatel[value]+"</option>");  
});` But still I am not sure how to iterate in JSP page(not using Javascript) . I tried this `<c:forEach var="strategy" items="${json_obj}" >
    <h1>${strategy}</h1>

  </c:forEach>` But Output is like `["ABC-1" "ABC-2" "ABC-3"