# How to Print JSON Array returned from controller class to jsp page

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsp

i am returning a json array from java class as return type and trying to display data on jsp page. everything is ok (as debugging says). But dont know the method (code/syntax) for jsp/html page.
**class**

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    public JSONArray get_user() {

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM USER_INFO";
        try {
            con = new connection.connect().getConnection();
            smt = con.createStatement();
            rset = smt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rset.next()) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("Email", rset.getString(2));
                obj.put("Password", rset.getString(3));
                jsonArray.put(obj);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }

        return jsonArray;
    }
```

**jsp**

```
<%
controller.fetch_user obj = new controller.fetch_user();
obj.get_user();
%>
<table>
<tr><td>Email</td><td>Password</td></tr>

 *** here i want to display all the records ****

</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Json object in jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756970/how-to-display-json-object-in-jsp)

Comment: noo ...  they have used JSTL , i dont

Comment: You did not say that. Why don't you use JSTL?

Comment: simple ,, i don't want to use. i just want to display in normal jsp. if u say that jsonarray can not be printed without JSTL, then its another matter.

Comment: help me on this ,,, how to access the "obj" that has "jsonArray" returned fron Controller.

Comment: If you don't want to use jstl you could do plain Java `<% for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
  arr.getJSONObject(i); //do something with the result
} %>` Take notice that I used the varaible arr as you return a JSONArray from get_user() not an JSONObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best solution for it instate of returning a json you can return pojo

Create your like

```
class UserInfo{
 private String email;
 private String Password;
 //setter and getter
}
```

and then reurn a list of userInfo

so your method will be

```
public List<UserInfo> get_user() {
    List<UserInfo> userInfoList = new AraayList<UserInfo>()
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM USER_INFO";
    try {
        con = new connection.connect().getConnection();
        smt = con.createStatement();
        rset = smt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rset.next()) {
            UserInfo obj = new UserInfo();
            obj.setEmail(rset.getString(2))
            obj.setPassword(rset.getString(3))

            userInfoList.add(obj);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }

    return userInfoList;
}
// for json object

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

public JSONArray get_user() {

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM USER_INFO";
    try {
        con = new connection.connect().getConnection();
        smt = con.createStatement();
        rset = smt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rset.next()) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("Email", rset.getString(2));
            obj.put("Password", rset.getString(3));
            jsonArray.put(obj);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }

    return jsonArray;
}
```

your jsp code is

```
<%
 controller.fetch_user obj = new controller.fetch_user();
 obj.get_user();
%>
<table>
<tr><td>Email</td><td>Password</td></tr>
for(UserInfo userInfo:obj){
<%
%>
<tr>
  <td><%=userInfo.getEmail()%><td>
  <td><%=userInfo.getPassword()%><td>
</tr> 
<%
 }
%>

</table>
```

and if your method still return jsonAraay the code will be

```
 <%
 controller.fetch_user obj = new controller.fetch_user();
JSONArray getArray = obj.get_user();
%>
<table>
<tr><td>Email</td><td>Password</td></tr>



<%
  for(int i = 0; i < getArray.size(); i++){
  JSONObject userInfo = getArray.getJSONObject(i);
%>
<tr>
  <td><%=userInfo.get("Email")%><td>
  <td><%=userInfo.get("Password")%><td>
</tr> 
<%
 }
%>

</table>
```

and in jsp code you can access this like in java you are access it

may be this will help you a lot

Comment: but friend, i want to use json,, thats why i have used it.

Comment: okay now i have updated your jsp code as per the json araay method please have a look on it.

Comment: JSONObject userInfo = getArray.getJSONArray(i);   For this i get error ,, json array cannot be converted into json object

Comment: and please refer http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html for all methods of jsonArray().